# Best way to parse a restapi that has a root node which is array or single object

Tags: javascript, rest

I'm building an application, and I need to parse various restapi responses that can be either a single object response, or an array. What would be the best way to go about this other than testing the element?

```
{
    "detail": {
    }
}
```

or

```
{
    "detail": []
}
```

Comment: Are these different responses being returned by _the same_ route, or _different_ routes?

Comment: It depends of how details works. If is a list of details, you should use `{"detail":[]}`, and the array containing the list of all details (string, objects, or whatever you need). If only a single detail is available  then use an object `{"detail":{}}`

Comment: I think there is an API Design problem. You should have a contract in which defined what type of response you will receive, it better should be an object or an array.
But you always can do a hack, as for me you can treat `detail` field always as array. Just test it like this `Array.isArray(detail)` and if not, put `detail` into newly created array `[detail]`, so you can write your business logic once.